# Uploading image to Azure and getting back its URL

Tags: ios, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am writing an iOS app for a service that runs on Azure. I need to be able to upload images (users' profile pictures) and get back the image's URL.

Azure's SDK for iOS doesn't seem to work with Blob, but only with Tables.

On my search, I've found tutorials like [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/mobile/resources-ios/), which gives an intro on the SDK, or [this one](http://chrisrisner.com/Storing-Images-from-iOS-in-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services) that shows how to store a base64 string of the image in a table, but that's not what I'm seeking.

Is it possible to upload images to the Blob? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an ios person, but have worked on apps that run on azure and communicate with ios for information hence this might be of your help as I am certain rest services can be accessed from ios.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx

Comment: That might be quite useful indeed. I'm going to take a good look at it.